# How to restore an expired token [AWS Cognito]?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS for my website. After 1 hour the token expires and the user pretty much can't do anything.

For now i'm trying to refresh the credentials like this:

```
 function getTokens(session) {
   return {
     accessToken: session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
     idToken: session.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
     refreshToken: session.getRefreshToken().getToken()
   };
 };


function getCognitoIdentityCredentials(tokens) {
  const loginInfo = {};
  loginInfo[`cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XXX`] = tokens.idToken;
  const params = {
    IdentityPoolId: AWSConfiguration.IdPoolId
    Logins: loginInfo
  };
  return new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);
 };


 if(AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh()) {
    clearInterval(messwerte_updaten);
    cognitoUser.refreshSession(cognitoUser.signInUserSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        var tokens = getTokens(session);
               
        AWS.config.credentials = getCognitoIdentityCredentials(tokens);
       
        AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          else {
            callLambda();
          }
       });
     }
   });
 }
```

the thing is, after 1hour, the login token gets refreshed without a problem, but after 2hrs i can't refresh the login token anymore.

i also tried using `AWS.config.credentials.get()`, `AWS.config.credentials.getCredentials()` and `AWS.config.credentials.refresh()`
which doesn't work either.

The error messages i'm getting are:

> Missing credentials in config
>
> Invalid login token. Token expired: 1446742058 >= 1446727732

Comment: are you getting your token by this [authentication flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html)? if so, you must configure a TokenDuration when calling [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html)

Comment: the maximum duration for credentials is 1 hour. this is what i've set it to.

Comment: so you'll need to request another to your developer identity

Comment: It is common for access tokens to expire after 3600 sec, after that we need to make another api call using a "refresh token", to get the access token again(a new one).

Comment: @InnocentCriminal I'm trying it like you've just mentioned since 2 days now, still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After almost 2 weeks i finally solved it.

You need the Refresh Token to receive a new Id Token. Once the Refreshed Token is acquired, update the AWS.config.credentials object with the new Id Token.

here is an example on how to set this up, runs smoothly!

```
refresh_token = session.getRefreshToken();   // you'll get session from calling cognitoUser.getSession()

if (AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh()) {

  cognitoUser.refreshSession(refresh_token, (err, session) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
      AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins['cognito-idp.<YOUR-REGION>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>']  = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      AWS.config.credentials.refresh((err)=> {
        if(err)  {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else{
          console.log("TOKEN SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED");
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually it's solved by intercepting http requests with additional logic.

```
function authenticationExpiryInterceptor() {
 // check if token expired, if yes refresh
}

function authenticationHeadersInterceptor() {
 // include headers, or no
}}
```

then with use of HttpService layer

```
  return HttpService.get(url, params, opts) {
     return authenticationExpiryInterceptor(...)
            .then((...) => authenticationHeadersInterceptor(...))
            .then((...) => makeRequest(...))
  }
```

It could be solved by proxy as well http://2ality.com/2015/10/intercepting-method-calls.html

In relation to AWS:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html

You're interested in:

- getPromise()
- refreshPromise()

Comment: i tried every method from aws, including `getPromise()` and `refreshPromise()` nothings works

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I implemented this:

First you need to authorize the user to the service and grant permissions:

**Sample request:**

Here is how I implemented this:

First you need to authorize the user to the service and grant permissions:

**Sample request:**

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token&
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'&
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj
grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id={your client_id}
code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&
redirect_uri={your rediect uri}
```

**This will return a Json something like:**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

```
{"access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd", "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je","id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r", "token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600}
```

**Now you need to get an access token depending on your scope:**

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'&
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj
grant_type=client_credentials&
scope={resourceServerIdentifier1}/{scope1} {resourceServerIdentifier2}/{scope2}
```

Json would be:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

```
{"access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd", "token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600}
```

Now this access_token is only valid for 3600 secs, after which you need to exchange this to get a new access token. To do this,

**To get new access token from refresh Token:**

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token >
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj
grant_type=refresh_token&
client_id={client_id}
refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

```
{"access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd", "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je", "id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r","token_type":"Bearer", "expires_in":3600}
```

You get the picture right.

If you need more details [go here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html).

Comment: please check my question again, i updated it.
Theres no problem in authorizing users, and granting them permissions, the only problem I (and many other people btw.) got is that i can't refresh the expired login token.

Comment: See the last part of my answer @tipsfedora. Hope it helps. You just need to make this POST request only after the previous access_token has expired i.e. after 1 hr after the last access_token was granted.

Comment: the first line of my routine  `if(AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh())`  is true after the token is expired (3600sec)

Comment: Sorry @tipsfedora I have never worked with AWS libraries before. In my experience sometimes these libraries just don't seem to work and many a time they perform flawlessly. That's why I prefer to make mannual API calls. Anyways nice question.

Comment: No Problem. At least, you tried to help me out, i really appreciate that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can refresh access token using AWS Amplify library:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    userPoolId: <USER_POOL_ID>,
    userPoolWebClientId: <USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID>
  }
});

try {
    const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const currentSession = currentUser.signInUserSession;
    currentUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
      // do something with the new session
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // whatever
  }
};
```

More discussion here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2560.