# iOS Swift, AWS Cognito User Pool, Unable to Refresh Access Token

Tags: swift, swift3, amazon-cognito

Looked at similar SO questions which didn't help me resolve the issue.

I am using AWS Cognito User Pools in our iOS App. We are able to successfully create and login the user. However **after about an Hr the access token is not available**, I understand from AWS Cognito documentation that the iOS SDK automatically refreshes ([also mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760577/2534233)) and obtains the token when it is not available, however I don't see this behaviour. The below code shows how I am trying to obtain the access token.

Using iOS SDK AWSCognitoIdentityProvider 2.6.7

Please advice how I can resolve the issue.

```
let mySession = self.pool.currentUser()?.getSession()

guard let accessToken = mySession?.result?.accessToken?.tokenString as? String else {
  print("Unable to obtain access token")
  self.handleSignOut() // Signing out the user since there is no access token       
  return
}
```

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: no.. will update if I get this resolved

Comment: I'm also facing this same issue. It's easy to see when it expires, but wtf, why is there barely any useful documentation on how to refresh the session.

Comment: Did you able to solve refresh session using Refresh Token for iOS. I am not able to find relevant documentation how we can refreshSession using AWSCognitoIdentityProvider

Answer (score 3):

`getSession()` returns an AWSTask.

You have to access the `tokenString` in the callback.

The following code works for me:

```
self.pool.currentUser()?.getSession().continueWith { task in

    if task.error == nil {
        let session = task.result! as AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession
        guard let accessToken = session.idToken?.tokenString; as? String else {
           print("Unable to obtain access token")
           self.handleSignOut() // Signing out the user since there is no access token       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this reauths you?

Comment: After refreshing the token using getSession() method does not calling method.
I've to re-run the app and then it's getting API response.
Is there any way to continue after refreshing the token and do not need to re-run the app?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cache `session` or `tokenString`. If you do, the AWS library has no way of executing code to know when it expires or refresh when it does. From what I have read (and what we have done with both the Android and iOS Cognito SDKs) the correct way is to call  `getSession()` each time you want a token. Under the hood, the AWS library will either return you a cached session immediately or go do the work to refresh the session (aka get a new token).

If you're not calling `getSession()` from the main thread, you could just block on the AWSTask returned from `getSession()`. Otherwise, this can be not-trivial to implement because you and AWSTask that will be completed later.

You can check the session's `expirationTime` property, and use a token from it if it isn't expired. But you're still going to handle the case where the session is expired and the AWS library needs to do a async work to refresh.